# Confused by generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

Can anyone explain why the following piece of code compiles?

```
List<Long> longNums = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
```

Is it due to type erasure?

If I have the following method:

```
public <T> T readProperty(String propName, Class<T> type);
```

How can I make sure that it will return, say a `List<Long>` and not a `List<String>`? Obviously, at the type of calling the method I can only supply `List.class` and pray.

```
//run and pray
List<Long> longNums = readProperty("prop", List.class);
```

It has already happened to me that such a method incorrectly assigned a list of String objects to a list of long number, and it wasn't until I ran it, that I saw the `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Simply - don't mix generics with raws.

Comment: How come you want to store String literal in `Long` List?

Comment: not a String literal, but a list of Strings. Maybe I should paraphrase

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't expect the program to behave correctly, because you **don't use** Generics correctly.

First, you should not mix Generics with Raws, which means that this statement

```
List<Long> longNums = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
```

is invalid (in terms of correctness). If it were:

```
List<Long> longNums = new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
```

it wouldn't even compile and you would get the error at compile-time (not at Runtime, which may be more confusing and scary).

So, in order to get compiled, your list should be defined as:

```
List<String> longNums = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
```

Further, with regards to this statement

```
//run and pray
List<Long> longNums = readProperty("prop", List.class);
```

there actually no way to make sure that `readProperty` will return `List<Long>`, so you will have to either do a cast or add a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation. The reason for this is the type-erasure feature of the compiler - the parameterized type `Long` get erased and it's gone at Runtime (when actually the `readProperty()` is executed and the value of `prob` is obtained via Reflection).

Comment: Yes, I know. The first part is more of an illustration example for the second part. What's the way to solve that?

Comment: Thanks. I wish there were really a way that I could specify in the parameters that I really, really expect a List<Long>. Something like (if it existed) List<Long>.class. My big problem is that the assignment works without a problem at runtime, and I only figure out about the issue, when I try to access an element of the list. I tried casting explicitly to (List<Long>) but that did not seem to help either.

Comment: If you can bet your life that at Runtime the list will contain only `Long` objects (so that there won't be any ClassCastExceptions), then you can just ignore the compiler warnings. :)

Comment: There is no compiler warning whatsoever in: List<Long> longNums = readProperty("prop", List.class); It goes totally clean.

Comment: Just a small thing, the *long* in `List<Long> longNums` isn't a parameter type but a *parametrised type*

Answer (score 1):

You missed diamond `<>` (this will not compile):

```
List<Long> longNums = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two","three"));
```

Comment: aaand this doesn't even compile :)

Comment: @kocko that's true. But at least this will prevent the runtime error :)

Answer (score 1):

These are two separate questions really.

```
List<Long> longNums = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
```

For source compatibility reasons a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) is allowed in these cases. You shouldn't rely on this because as you can see, it defeats the whole idea of generics.

As for the second question, you can sidestep the issue by doing something like this:

```
public <T> List<T> readListProperty(String propName, Class<T> type);
...
List<Long> longNums = readProperty("prop", Long.class);
```

It's more of a workaround than a solution and isn't always applicable. (For example when you need even more complex return types, like `Map<String,List<String>>`)

Comment: I can't touch the method signature unfortunately. Also, I tried explicit casting of the result to List<Long> but that did not help either. The assignment still goes on without an issue. I only figure out about the casting problem, when I try to access an element of the list.

Comment: That's unfortunately how it is if you can't change the method, there's no compile-time trick to get you around. You can check the result manually at runtime, but checking a single element isn't enough, you need to check all of them because it is possible your list will contain 6 `Long`s, followed by a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a List as `ArrayList`, java doesn't know what kind of object are in it. You can assign it to an `ArrayList<Long>`, but you'll get an error when you call methods or properties on items, because the type doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Generic class:

```
public abstract class GenericClass<T> {

private T managedClass;
public List<T> readListProp(String propName,T object){
    //do stuff using T type instead of Long,String,Double,etc
}
Other classes:
public class FirstClass extends GenericClass<String>
{...
//you have a class where T from generic is replaced with String
} 
public class SecClass extends GenericClass<Double>
{...
//you have a class where T from generic is replaced with Double
}
```

Comment: This answer seems like it has nothing to do with the question. If it does, please explain!